# Attaching selectors or child elements to variable name that holds dom element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, children

I saved dom elements to variable names trying to increase performance (not having to traverse the dom everytime).

```
listGroupsExport = $('#listGroupsExport');
```

But now I want to call out each LI of that UL.  Is there a way to still use the variable name and do the equivalent of **$('#listGroupsExport.li')** using the var name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the descendants of your element.

```
listGroupsExport.find('li');
```

if you want to just get the children then:

```
listGroupsExport.children('li');
```

Another way is to use context in the selector:

```
$('li', listGroupsExport); //But find will be faster
```

By the way your selector should anyways be `$('#listGroupsExport .li'); //Note the space`

Comment: I was going to comment about how your selector should never involve children, that find will always be faster, but i think u covered the options. context in selectors is super old school though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the descedents of an element

```
listGroupsExport.find('li')
```